# What are the criteria for the "Curious" Badge?

Tags: support, badges

The "Curious" Badge is awarded when you "ask a good question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record." What is meant by "good question" in this? It's not the score of 25 required of a "Good Question;" is it just questions with positive net votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Relevant Meta.SE post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

A well-received question is a question that isn't closed, isn't deleted, and has score>0.

A positive question record is defined by the formula:

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
```

(A question that is negatively scored, and closed, and then deleted, will count triple.)

Comment: From this formula, it appears that your 5 "good questions" must have positive scores, but that questions with a score of 0 still count in your favor for the "positive question record" aspect. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @Dan Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok. In that case (and I don't know why I can't submit this as an edit suggestion - app doesn't say why and hover text, on desktop site's disabled edit link, isn't accessible from mobile browser), perhaps your final sentence should say "over half of your questions must be non-negative" instead?

Comment: @Dan I've edited it out completely, because it's not actually a correct statement; a negative, closed, deleted post counts thrice.

Comment: Oh, I considered that adequately covered by "**over** half".