# Why doesn't my curious badge count all my well received questions?

Tags: support, bug, badges

After reading [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) and reviewing [this question and answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5780/what-are-the-criteria-for-the-curious-badge) I can't seem to work out why the progress noted for my 'curious' badge is only 2/5 instead of 3/5.

I don't have a positive question record:

```
(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5
(4               - 1                  - 1      - 1      )/4                = 0.25
```

(darn that stupid question that got downvoted, closed and then deleted! Perhaps a speedy 'delete before it gets closed' would have saved me a point!)

So I can't earn this badge until I ask at least one more positively received question that is neither closed nor deleted, but I have three well received, open, undeleted questions - wouldn't that mean that the badge would read as 3/5, positive question record required?

---

Added both bug and support tags, as while I'm guessing there's some functionality here that means the tracking is, in fact, correct, this could be an incorrect guess. Also, if I'm right, maybe there's a good place to clarify how this feature works more fully.

Comment: When did you ask the deleted question?

Comment: @Laurel May 30. Are you thinking that if I got a non-positive question record it would stop updating the number or something?

Comment: No but it could've prevented a well received question from counting, if they were asked on the same day I think. From the linked post: "If you ask at least one well-received question in a UTC day and none of your questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed, you get one more day of credit toward the badge." (Assuming you're right about when you asked the question this does not appear to be the case here.) It's possible that there's a bug; something similar happened [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305183/323179) it seems.

Comment: I've asked another well received question buy my question record (which therefore should be 0.5) still doesn't report as positive... I wonder if there's a delay in when it's updated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script that checks the progress for this badge only runs once per day, as the question has to be well-received at the end of the day (UTC time). That also means the question must have had a positive net score. That means that you don't get the progress for the question you asked today in the progress bar today. But tomorrow it should get updated and show 3/5.

About the reason why it currently doesn't show 3/5: [Can you take different archetype options at different levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/123387/revisions) was closed at some point and as [Laurel pointed out](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8186/why-doesnt-my-curious-badge-count-all-my-well-received-questions#comment26180_8186) (emphasis mine):

> If you ask at least one well-received question in a UTC day and **none of your questions that day are** deleted, downvoted, or **closed**, you get one more day of credit toward the badge.

The fact that your question was closed prevents it from being counted towards the badge, even if it was reopened shortly thereafter.

Currently only [If an attack alerts someone to your presence, can their initiative save them from being surprised in time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127794/34863) and [Are there ways other than Kensei Weapons or Hex Warrior to use an ability other than STR for non-finesse melee weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127945/34863) haven't been closed and had a net positive score on their first day of being on the site as noted by the daily running script.